# Displaying contents of $page in Vuepress

Tags: javascript, arrays, static-site, vuepress

Within $page.authors i have the contributor name and email for all contributors to a specific document in my Vuepress site the output for {{ $page.authors }} is

```
[ { "username": "Chris Clark", "email": "chris@example.com" } ]
```

I would like to see only the username so tried {{ $page.authors.username }} which returns nothing.  Could someone please tell me how to display only the username and could this be added to all pages on my Vuepress site without having to add the code to every page?